# Get CommandParameter value from GestureRecognizers in Xamarin froms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm sending `CommandParameter` to `TapGestureRecognizer`, and it was available in object parameter of my `OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped` function. But I'm unable to extract value from it. How can I fix this?

My list view (XAML markup):

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewEvents" RowHeight="120" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Padding="5">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="Large" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Text="{Binding UploadTitle}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding UploadDescription}" Font="Small"  TextColor="Gray" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>
                    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding AttachPath}" Aspect="AspectFill">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"
                                NumberOfTapsRequired="2"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding AttachPath_New}"
                                />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding FileName}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

My C# page :

```
void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
        string fullPath = "";
        Image imageSender = (Image)sender;

        if (imageSender.GestureRecognizers.Count > 0)
        {
            fullPath = imageSender.GestureRecognizers[0].ToString();
        }
        DownloadFile(imageSender.Source.GetValue(UriImageSource.UriProperty).ToString());
}
```

Here I'm getting my value:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to convert the entire GestureRecognizer to a string, not just its CommandParameter property.

```
void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    string fullPath = "";
    Image imageSender = (Image)sender;
    if (imageSender.GestureRecognizers.Count > 0)
    {
        var gesture = (TapGestureRecognizer)imageSender.GestureRecognizers[0];
        fullPath = (string)gesture.CommandParameter;
    }
    DownloadFile(imageSender.Source.GetValue(UriImageSource.UriProperty).ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another solution you can use is to typecast EventArgs to TappedEventArgs and expose the Parameter.
So to access the CommandParameter you would write the following:

```
private void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var te = (TappedEventArgs)e;
string parameter = (string)te.Parameter;
....
```