# Xamarin listview button click get command argument value

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this listview

```
<ListView x:Name="LocationsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfFuel}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout>
          <StackLayout>
            <Button CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
          </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

With the code behind event I want to get the CommandParameter which is part of the ItemsSource list, the Id value.

I'm doing this:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    int Idvalue = btn.Id;
}
```

With this approach the app is complaining that the button Id is guid value but in the list I have Id as integer, so I'm assuming the Id is some kind of identification for the button itself not the actual Id value from the items source.

What are my options to find out on button click the listview id or some other property in that list?

Comment: The problem is that `CommandParamter` is used for `Commands` while you're using the `Clicked` event handler. You can check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50912352/10608418. To see how you can extract the value of the `CommandParameter` inside an event handler. But in my opinion the cleaner way is to use a `Command` instead of the `Clicked` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only get the **CommandParameter**  in **Command** .

In xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="xxx.MainPage"
             x:Name="contentPage">//set the name of contentPage here
```

```
<StackLayout>
         <Button CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference contentPage}, Path=BindingContext.ClickCommand}"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

And in your ViewModel:

```
public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }

//...

public MyViewModel()
{
   //...

   ClickCommand = new Command((arg)=> {

    Console.WriteLine(arg);

  });
}
```

**arg** here is the **CommandParameter** that you binding the value of property **Id**

Comment: Hi Lucas. The `>` device is for a "blockquote", which is used to indicate that material being _quoted_ was spoken or written by someone else. So, if you are quoting from a book, speech, film, magazine, manual etc, it is appropriate to use it then. If you are just marking up titles or introductions to your own code blocks, ordinary paragraph text makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can give you two solutions to this.
1. Instead of using a Button inside Nested StackLayout you can use ItemSelected Event of Listview. In that method you can get the entire Item using e.SelectedItem and the cast it to your class type

```
ListView.ItemSelected += (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    var item = (YourClass) e.SelectedItem;

    // now you can any property of YourClass.  
};
```

2. You can find the highest Parent and then get it's BindingContext.

   private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       StackLayout stc = ((sender as Button).Parent as StackLayout).Parent as StackLayout;
   // Then get the BindingContext

   }